How can I implement this markdown syntax into my docusaurus project?
I'm currently doing a project on Docusaurus, I have pre-written md files with this type of syntax:
h1. Title

{{toc}}

h3. Subtitle

# ...
# ...

Paragraph
<pre>
<code class="java">
...
</code>
</pre>

But docusaurus is accepting md files written in this way:
# Title

### Subtitle

Paragraph
```java
code
'```
(the ' is just for proper displaying in stack overflow)

I tried to rewrite the code of a file to the syntax docusaurus accepts but it's giving too many problems, like parsing and syntax ones, and on a 3000 line long code it's simply impossible to manage.
I asked ChatGPT for help, tried searching for similar past issues, tried downloading some plugins suggested by the bot (even not existing ones, lol) but I can't seem to reach a solution to the problem.
I should've been able to just copy and paste all the existing files I have so that I don't have to rewrite all the code.

I'd use https://pandoc.org to convert it: pandoc -f jira -t markdown
